# Dialogflow set speech response as default auto response

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es, webhooks, chatbot, speech

I'm trying to set the response that answers the questions posed to dialogflow to automatically be spoken/set to speech as a default in web-chat.
What I mean is, when the user asks a question, I want the bot to automatically return with a speech response so that the user doesn't have to click the "speack" button on the message.
I'm using a C# API webhook to set the responses to the questions.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot set the Dialogflow generated Audio as the default response. It depends on how the platform, in this case the web-chat, decides to handle the information retrieved by Dialogflow. If you have control over the web-chat code, then you can request Dialogflow to return an audio by sending the [outputAudioConfig parameter in the DerectIntentRequest](http://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-dotnet/docs/Google.Cloud.Dialogflow.V2/api/Google.Cloud.Dialogflow.V2.DetectIntentRequest.html), and then have the web-chat code to play the audio.

If you don't have control over the web-chat, then you'll need to know how they're processing the Dialogflow's response so you can adapt your responses.